# use django: from "python manage.py shell" to python script

Tags: python, django

I can move to a python project directory (say c:\www\myproject) and then issue

```
   python manage.py shell
```

and then I can use all modules from django project, say the following piece of commands from the shell command:

```
import settings 
from django.template import Template, Context

t=Template("My name is {myname}.")
c=Context({"myname":"John"})
f = open('write_test.txt', 'w')
f.write(t.render(c))
f.close
```

now, when I tried to collect all my commands into a python script, say "mytest.py", I cannot execute the script.  I must missed something important.

I issued python mytest.py

then I got `Import error: could not import settings` Is it on sys path?"

I'm in the project directory where settings.py resides.....

Could some one help me out?

thanks.

Comment: Can you post the error? You most likely have a PYTHONPATH problem. Since your question mentioned the C: drive, I assume you are on Windows. http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django script to access model objects without using manage.py shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047204/django-script-to-access-model-objects-without-using-manage-py-shell)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try using a [Django management command](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/#writing-custom-django-admin-commands) instead.

```
# myproject/myapp/management/commands/my_command.py

from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand
from django.template import Template, Context
from django.conf import settings

class Command(NoArgsCommand):
    def handle_noargs(self, **options):
        t=Template("My name is {myname}.")
        c=Context({"myname":"John"})
        f = open('write_test.txt', 'w')
        f.write(t.render(c))
        f.close
```

And then (if you follow the docs) you will be able to execute the command in the following fashion:

```
python manage.py my_command
```

Comment: See my other answer, that might just do the trick. However if you want a tidy place for your scripts, then management commands might be the way to go.

Answer (score 23):

This method is [deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#django-core-management-setup-environ) in Django 1.4. Use `django.conf.settings.configure()` instead
 (see @adiew's answer for example code).

Old method follows.

Put this at the beginning of your script

```
from django.core.management import setup_environ
import settings
setup_environ(settings)
```

This is really what the manage.py does behind the scene. To see it view the Django source in `django/core/management/__init__.py`. After executing these lines everything should be just like in `./manage.py shell`.

Comment: This has been depreciated in Django 1.4.  use @adieu instead `from django.conf import settings;settings.configure()`

Comment: For me, this is the __right__ answer, still (as of Django 1.5 for me). `settings.configure()` is sometimes not enough

Answer (score 11):

Try put these two lines at the beginning of your script:

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure() # check django source for more detail

# now you can import other django modules
from django.template import Template, Context
```

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE:** From [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853649/executing-python-script-from-django-shell).

`./manage.py shell < myscript.py`

Answer (score 2):

To import Django's settings use:

```
from django.conf import settings
```

Comment: i put "from django.conf import settings" as the first line of my script, but still python cannot import settings.....am I using it the right way?  thanks!

Comment: The reason I use management commands is because Django puts a bunch of stuff on the Python path when it starts up (such as `django`) and using a management command harnesses this. `python manage.py shell` starts up a regular version of the `python` interrupter but with the added environment. For example try executing your statements in the regular python interrupter rather than the django shell.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of manually adding things to your python script, or having to fit in the management command format, in case this is not something that needs to stay around long, you can get all the benefits of the Django environment by running your script with `./manage.py runscript <myscript.py>`

... but if your script is in your project folder, then you can just add this line to the top of the python script: `import os; os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'`

Comment: Using runscript is a bit more complicated, but nicely summarized [here](http://blog.brendel.com/2012/01/how-to-use-djangextensions-runscript.html)

Answer (score 1):

Saw in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24456404/4200284 a good solution for **Django >= 1.7** and in case someone uses **django-configurations** this worked for me:

```
import sys, os, django

sys.path.append('/path/to/project')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.local") # path to config

## if using django-configurations
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_CONFIGURATION", "Local")
from configurations import importer
importer.install()

django.setup() ## apparently important for django 1.7

from foo.models import Bar

print Bar.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another variant: I wrote and often use a management command "run" which has the advantage that scripts can see their command-line parameters:

http://lino-framework.org/api/lino.management.commands.run.html