# Django reverse returns different values when called from WSGI or shell

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have deployed a Django project on an Apache server using mod_wsgi, using a prefix URL `/mysite`, i.e. my Apache configuration contains

```
WSGIScriptAlias /mysite /var/www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
```

When `reverse('myview')` (from `django.core.urlresolvers`) is called from the web server process, it returns the expected URL `/mysite/myview`, i.e. including the prefix URL.

However, when `reverse('myview')` is called from a script (e.g. a cronjob), not through the web server process, only `/myview` is returned without the desired prefix URL. My example script looks like this:

```
import sys
import os
import django

sys.path.append('/var/www/mysite')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
django.setup()

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
print reverse('myview') # prints '/myview'
```

Is there a way to include the prefix URL when running outside of the web server context, so that the same `reverse('myview')` code can be run from both contexts and returns the same value?

Comment: While not an exact duplicate (WSGI vs. regular python script, as opposed to Django shell vs. regular python script), the solutions to http://stackoverflow.com/q/4847469/674064 might apply here, too.

Comment: Use `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME` setting

Comment: I tried adding `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/mysite'` in `settings.py`, but it makes no difference to the output of `reverse('myview')` when called from a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django only expects a `SCRIPT_NAME` in the context of a web request. It is retrieved from the WSGI environment or the `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME` setting and set for the duration of the request.

To manually set a script name, use `set_script_prefix()`:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import set_script_prefix

set_script_prefix('/mysite')
```

Note that this is 1) a private, undocumented function, and 2) stored in a thread-local variable.

Comment: This does work, so I'll accept the answer. However, it would be nicer not to have to resort to an undocumented function. Is there a reason that there isn't a nicer way, i.e. am I using `reverse` in a way I shouldn't? My use case is a cronjob which sends emails containing links to the web site, which should obviously contain the correct prefix URL.